# Meteor user accounts if not selected remember me then logout on browser close?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using meteor user accounts for login . Now I have customized login forms and used their methods to login. Now i want to add remember me check box. If its not selected user should be logged out. Otherwise he can resume his session unless he manually log out. Any idea or concept what ever you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can not test this at the moment, but you could use `onbeforeunload` or `onunload` events, and process the logout in that step

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    Meteor.logout();
};
```

Comment: let me try it somewhere in my code. Will get back to you soon

Comment: It also run on browser refresh..so when i refresh the page user logs out..so cant use this

Comment: Add `return "Leaving this page will log you out. Continue?"` to prevent accidental logouts.